# no className proposition on classNames passed from props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to pass my `className` via a props, which works like this

```
interface Props {
  width: string;
  heigth: string;
  children: React.ReactChild;
  classNames?:string ;
}
```

this is how I use it inside another component

```
<State
  width="w-28"
  heigth="h-4"
  classNames="bg-white"
>
 <p className="line-clamp-1 max-w-[9rem]">{data.title}</p>
</State>
```

the problem is that when using control space on the state classname prop it does not provide me the tailwindcss options. It works fine when using it in the className inside the

tag.

this is what it shows when using the

className

[image]

and this is when using the props

[image]

I am guessing that is because my `className` props is a string so it does not know it is actually a className.

any idea on how to make it work?

thx

Comment: Do you have a pre-known list of className's?

Comment: No, the vscode tailwindcss intelisense extension knows these are classes